# Python LeakIX client - Unable to extract pulled info from l9format instance

Tags: python, security

I am using the Python client for LeakIX, and am running into issues regarding getting the pulled info.

Below is the code I am running to query "komatsu.com" and the output that I get.

```
# File located in example/example_client.py
from leakix import Client
from leakix.query import MustQuery, MustNotQuery, RawQuery
from leakix.field import PluginField, CountryField, TimeField, Operator
from leakix.plugin import Plugin
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

API_KEY = "API_KEY"
CLIENT = Client(api_key=API_KEY)

def example_get_leak_raw_query():
    raw_query = 'komatsu.com'
    query = RawQuery(raw_query)
    response = CLIENT.get_leak(queries=[query])
    for i in response.json():
        print(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    example_get_leak_raw_query()
```

> <l9format.l9format.L9Event model at 0x2d9c1e4e1d0>

The result is an l9format instance, not sure how to access the info inside of it. I will attach the documentation and the repo to the client. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

LeakIX Documentation: https://docs.leakix.net/docs/ 
LeakIX Python Client: https://github.com/LeakIX/LeakIXClient-Python